# How can I update the function in the protocol without Xcode error?

Tags: swift, protocols

I want to update the function as in the comment, but I used this function in many places, so how can I update this function without making any changes?

```
protocol Fooable {
    func foo1() //-> foo1(toggle: Bool)
    func foo2()
}

class FooController: Fooable {
    
    func foo1() {
        
    }
    
    func foo2() {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to change the type signature of a protocol method. Why would you not want to (and need to) change the signature of the method in all conforming types as well? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the signature, you must change the implementations.

If you'd like to keep the changes at a minimum *at the call sites*, provide a default value in the implementation.

```
protocol Fooable {
    foo1(toggle: Bool)
}

class FooController: Fooable {
    
    func foo1(toggle:Bool = false) {
        
    }
}
```